Mysql - Filas con valores iguales, mostrar los otros valores en diferentes columnas
Tengo el siguiente problema:
En la tabla "ficharegistro_persona" se registran las personas dueñas de una casa, si es un solo no hay problema pero si son 2. se agrupan de la siguiente manera:
Idficharegistro -  es el código de venta ;  idpersona  - es el código de persona(con ello jalamos de otra tabla datos como el nombre, dni y demás) ; titular - 1 si lo fuese ó 0 si fuese cotitular.
En la siguiente imagen observaremos las dos tablas y el resultado esperado.

Mi select en mysql es:
SELECT
 `ficharegistro_persona`.`idficharegistro`,
 group_concat(`persona`.`razonsocial`) as Titular_Cotitular,
 `persona`.`razonsocial` AS `cliente`
FROM
`ficharegistro_persona`
 INNER JOIN `persona` ON (`ficharegistro_persona`.`idpersona` = `persona`.`idpersona`)
 where idficharegistro = 11069
group by `ficharegistro_persona`.`idficharegistro` ;

pero me sale errado :

Por favor su ayuda. Gracias de antemano.

Asumiendo que los únicos valores posibles para titular son 1 y 0 (si hubiera más, debes definir qué hacer para esos casos), puedes lograr el resultado usando CASE WHEN.
La consulta sería:
SELECT
 `ficharegistro_persona`.`idficharegistro`,
  GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN `ficharegistro_persona`.`titular`=1 THEN `persona`.`razonsocial` END) AS `Titular_Cotitular`, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN `ficharegistro_persona`.`titular`=0 THEN `persona`.`razonsocial` END) AS `cliente`,
  GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN `ficharegistro_persona`.`titular`=1 THEN `persona`.`nrodocumento` END) AS `dni titular`, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN `ficharegistro_persona`.`titular`=0 THEN `persona`.`nrodocumento` END) AS `dni cotitular`
FROM
  `ficharegistro_persona`
INNER JOIN 
  `persona` ON (`ficharegistro_persona`.`idpersona` = `persona`.`idpersona`)
WHERE 
  `idficharegistro` = 11069
GROUP BY 
  `ficharegistro_persona`.`idficharegistro`;

A continuación un fiddle completo:
CREATE TABLE `ficharegistro_persona` (`idficharegistro` int, `idpersona` int, `titular` int);

CREATE TABLE `persona` (`idpersona` int, `razonsocial` varchar(150), `nrodocumento` int);

insert into `ficharegistro_persona` values 
  (11069,19870,1),(11069,19871,0),(11069,19872,0),
  (11070,19873,1),(11070,19874,0);


insert into `persona` values 
  (19870,'ARRUNATEGUI',111),(19871,'NANFUÑAY',222),(19872,'OTRO MÁS',333),
  (19873,'BBB',444),(19874,'CCC',555),(19875,'DDD',777);



SELECT
 `ficharegistro_persona`.`idficharegistro`,
  GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN `ficharegistro_persona`.`titular`=1 THEN `persona`.`razonsocial` END) AS `Titular_Cotitular`, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN `ficharegistro_persona`.`titular`=0 THEN `persona`.`razonsocial` END) AS `cliente`,
  GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN `ficharegistro_persona`.`titular`=1 THEN `persona`.`nrodocumento` END) AS `dni titular`, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN `ficharegistro_persona`.`titular`=0 THEN `persona`.`nrodocumento` END) AS `dni cotitular`
FROM
  `ficharegistro_persona`
INNER JOIN 
  `persona` ON (`ficharegistro_persona`.`idpersona` = `persona`.`idpersona`)
WHERE 
  `idficharegistro` = 11069
GROUP BY 
  `ficharegistro_persona`.`idficharegistro`;




idficharegistro
Titular_Cotitular
cliente
dni titular
dni cotitular




11069
ARRUNATEGUI
NANFUÑAY,OTRO MÁS
111
222,333



fiddle
